# Laravel Eloquent Construction

Tags: laravel

i have this tables:

```
Attendances
id | member_id | attended_at
1  | 1         | 01/01/2018
2  | 2         | 01/01/2018
3  | 3         | 01/01/2018
4  | 4         | 01/01/2018
5  | 5         | 01/01/2018

Members
id | church_id
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 3
4  | 2
5  | 3

Churches
id | church_location
1  | Olongapo
2  | Bataan
3  | Subic
```

My question is from the Attendances table, i need to know how many attended on each church locations, below is the result i needed:

```
Olongapo - 2
Bataan - 1
Subic - 2
```

Can you please help me fill the code below?

```
$attendances = Attendance::
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A raw SQL giving that result will be the following:

```
select church_location, count(a.id) from churches as c
inner join members as m on c.id = m.church_id
inner join attendances as a on a.member_id = m.id
group by c.id;
```

now to translate that in Laravel I would start with the church model, instead of the other way around.

```
$attendances = Church::with(['members' => function($query) {
    $query->join('attendances as a', 'a.member_id', '=', 'members.id');
}])
->select([
  'church_location',
  DB::raw('count(a.id) as attendance')
]
->groupBy('id')->get();
```

You might need to modify it a bit, as I did the translation into laravel without the existing models, but it should be close to what you want. The raw query works for sure as I tried it.

-- EDIT

Another thing to note is that you will have to have the relationships setup in your models as well for the code above to work.

-- EDIT Using the Query Builder

```
DB::table('churches as c')
->select([
    'c.church_location',
    DB::raw('count(a.id) as attendance')
])
->join('members as m', 'm.church_id', '=', 'c.id')
->join('attendances as a', 'm.member_id', '=', 'm.id')
->groupBy('c.id')
->get();
```

Comment: tried, but all churches only resulting to 1 count, example: Olongapo - 1 ; Bataan - 1, any thoughts?

Comment: it is really hard to find while not having the models. You can try to group them by explicitly noting which id, for example `groupBy('churches.id')` and see if it works, or try the Query Builder option that I've added now.